# Повторное введение числа в Scanner. Почему при двух блоках try/catch, программа позволяет вводить значения до выполнения условия, а при одном выдает Е

Tags: java, scanner

```
public class Loop1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Loop1 l1 = new Loop1();
        l1.scanner();

    }
    public void scanner()  throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите число: ");
        long x = 0;
        while (x == 0) {
            try {
                x = scan.nextLong();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Повтори попытку: ");
                try {
                    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    x = scan1.nextLong();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    System.out.println("Ты мне надоел.");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(x);


    }
}
```

Comment: А при одном блоке try/catch при повторном некорректном вводе выдает исключение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

зачем пробрасывать исключение `throws Exception`, если оно обрабатывается в методе??

зачем вложенность `try` в `try` ??

а теперь по делу.

`nextLong();` cчитывает число, и когда ты вводишь число и нажимаешь `enter` число записывается, а  перевод строки `"\n"` остаётся(или возврат каретки, уже точно не помню).

поэтому используй метод `next` либо `nextLine`   и так как эти методы возвращают строку, а у тебя long, надо парсить. и менять `x = scan.nextLong();` на

```
x = Long.parseLong(scan.nextLine());
x = Long.parseLong(scan1.nextLine());
```

или

```
x = Long.parseLong(scan.next());
x = Long.parseLong(scan1.next());
```

Comment: Вот про вложенный try в try я и спрашиваю. Когда я убираю вложенный try, то после второй попытки некорректно веденого значения выбрасывает исключения, а с вложенным try в try, я могу вводить некорректные значения сколько хочу раз, очевидно пока я не введу правильно. Попробовал с Вашим вариантом и с одним блоком try/catch, так же выбрасывает исключения после второй попытки некорректного ввода значения.

Comment: @Charismatic и что выбрасывает? у меня и с одним и с вложенном работает нормально.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "sa"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
 at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:714)
 at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:839)
 at zadanie2.Loop12.scannerNumber(Loop12.java:23)
 at zadanie2.Loop12.main(Loop12.java:9)
Покажите пожалуйста как Вы сделали, возможно я где-то ошибаюсь.

Comment: Все получилось, моя ошибка. Спасибо большое за помощь.